# Create Drop-down List with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop-down list in `Cell E5`.

My range of values for the drop-down should come from `Range(A1:A5)` in `Sheet2` and `Range(C1:C7)` in `Sheet2`. However, my code below is not working, it runs an error 1004 at `Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5 & Sheet2!$C$1:$C$7"` I suspect it has something to do with this line...`Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5 & Sheet2!$C$1:$C$7"` . Does anyone know how I can add two ranges into my `Formula1`?

Also, I dont want the blanks in the ranges to appear in the Drop-down list but `.IgnoreBlank = True` still shows the blanks in the drop-down list.
This is my code thus far, any help is genuinely appreciated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5")) Is Nothing Then

With Range("e5").Validation
.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5 & Sheet2!$C$1:$C$7"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.ErrorTitle = "Warning"
.ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from the drop-down list available."
.ShowError = True

End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To add multiple columns data, use a unique collection and then feed that to the DV

Comment: hi @SiddharthRout can I get a hint on how I should start on that? So sorry

Comment: I posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. Still if you do then simply ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add multiple columns data, use a unique collection and then feed that to the DV in a comma delimited string. See this example. Change as applicable.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim DVList As String

    '~~> Loop through the data range
    For Each rng In Sheet2.Range("A1:A5,C1:C5")
        '~~> Ignore blanks
        If Len(Trim(rng.Value)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Create a unique list
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add rng.Value, CStr(rng.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next rng

    '~~> Concatenate with "," as delimiter
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        DVList = DVList & col.Item(i) & ","
    Next i

    '~~> Feed it to the DV
    With Sheet1.Range("E5").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
        AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:=DVList
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this work so simply well.....you're a genius!! 
Can I just ask...what does the portion  `'~~> Concatenate with "," as delimiter` mean? I dont get that line even after your comment .. ><

Comment: when you manually create a DV list, you can enter `a,b,c,d`? So the code is doing that. It is passing `1,2,3,4...`

Comment: ah.... so sorry..., so it is merely counting the no. of items in the cols?

Comment: No it is joining then with a comma

Answer (score 0):

the property Formula1:="*Expression*" does not allow splitted tables. As Siddharth Rout wrote - as a work  aorund - first you have to collect all values in a single table or a string.

Also the IgnoreBlank property does not ignore blanks, but is considering the cell value as valid even the cell content is blank. So, while collecting table content skip blank cells.